# python grammar mistake invalid syntax

Tags: python

The code has an error which I could not find.

```
def  cut_rod(p, n): 
    if (n == 0): 
        return 0
    q = p[n];
    for i in range(1,n):
        q = max(q, p[i] + cut_rod(p, n - i)); 
        return q; 
    return; 

# your code goes here
p1 = [1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30]; 
n1 = len(p1); 
print n1; 
a = cut_rod(p1,n1);
```

Comment: How do you know there's an error? Posting the error traceback will help people help you!

Comment: Python uses zero-based indexing. That means that the first item in a list is at index 0, not 1. When you use `n1 = len(p1)`, the item at that index is actually right after the end of the list: nonexistent. You should use `n1 = len(p1) - 1`.

Comment: Hi, zondo, I am new to Python. The error says "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded". Thanks for the replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your code is that the index `n1` by definition does not exist in your list. Python lists indices start at 0, so a list with length 3 only has indices 0-2.

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(len(mylist))
# 3
print(mylist[3])
# IndexError!
print(mylist[2])
# "c"
```

Instead of this:

```
n1 = len(p1)
```

Try this:

```
n1 = len(p1) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this.

Comment: I hope it helps. In general, the more info you include in your question, the better. Stackoverflow has pretty detailed guidelines on [how to write good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).